# Log PHP exceptions in Laravel Log

Tags: php, exception, logging, laravel

I'm starting to create a custom log feature for my application in Laravel 4 everything works fine for custom messages but when i try to log the exception messages within `try..catch(Exception $e)` doesn't write this exception on the log file.

```
<?php namespace Api\ApplicationEvents;

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

class LogWritter {

    public static function write( $logMessage, $logLevel)
    {
        $date = date('d_m_y');

        $logFile = public_path() . '\logs\log_' . $date . '.log';

        if ( !file_exists($logFile)) {
            $fp = fopen($logFile, 'w');
            fwrite($fp, '');
            fclose($fp);
        }

        $log = new Logger('Menu App Log: ');

        switch ($logLevel) {
            case 'Info':
                $log->pushHandler( new StreamHandler($logFile, Logger::INFO) ); 
                break;

            case 'Warn':
                $log->pushHandler( new StreamHandler($logFile, Logger::WARNING) ); 
                break;

            case 'Error':
                $log->pushHandler( new StreamHandler($logFile, Logger::ERROR) ); 
                break;
        }

        $log->addInfo($logMessage);
    }
}
?>
```

The call of the function is like that:

```
try { 
// code goes here 
} catch (Exception $e) {
   $exception = $e->getMessage();
   Api\ApplicationEvents\LogWritter::write( $exception, 'Error');
}
```

But for now can't write the exception message in the log file

Can somebody help me to get this going right, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried testing your `Api\ApplicationEvents\LogWritter::write( $exception, 'Error');` code in isolation?

e.g. try this to test your code works

```
try { 
  throw new RuntimeException() 
} catch (Exception $e) {
   $exception = $e->getMessage();
   Api\ApplicationEvents\LogWritter::write( $exception, 'Error');
}
```

If that works fine you know there is nothing wrong with your class and method.

Edit:

Try this:

```
switch ($logLevel) {
    case 'Warn':
        $log->pushHandler( new StreamHandler($logFile, Logger::WARNING) ); 
        $log->addWarning($logMessage);
        break;

    case 'Error':
        $log->pushHandler( new StreamHandler($logFile, Logger::ERROR) ); 
        $log->addError($logMessage);            
        break;

    default:
        $log->pushHandler( new StreamHandler($logFile, Logger::INFO) ); 
        $log->addInfo($logMessage);
}
```

Comment: The question here is why when i do `try { .. } catch(Exception $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }` shows the exception in the browser output?, this should not be the same to get the exception and send it to my log function?

Comment: You have no default in your switch. That may be causing an issue as if it cant find a switch you wont have setup a push handler